# Is $ mA \otimes B = m(A\otimes B)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products, flatness

I am writing a proof which would simplify if the following was true.

Let $ A $ and $ B $ be two $ R $-modules, and suppose that $ B $ is flat over $ R $. Let $ m \in \mathbb{Z} $. Is it true that $$ mA \otimes _{ R }  B = m(A\otimes _ { R}  B)  ? $$

Answer (score 2):

By flatness, if $A'$ is a submodule of $A$ then one can identify
$A'\otimes_R B$ with a submodule of $A\otimes_R B$, namely as that generated by
all $a'\otimes b$ with $a'\in A'$.

With this observation it's surely obvious that $mA\otimes_R B$
is the submodule of $A\otimes_R B$ generates by the elements $(ma)\otimes b=m(a\otimes b)$
and that is $m(A\otimes_R B)$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Notice that flatness is quite important, since as I commented earlier here, if I take $ A = R $, $ B = J $ an ideal, and take some ideal $ I $ instead of $ (m) $, then $ I \otimes J = RI \otimes J = I ( R \otimes J ) = IJ $, which is definitely not true in general.

Comment: More generally, you could argue that $ (IA)\otimes B = I(A\otimes B)$ for any ideal $ I $, when $ B $ is flat.

When $ B $ is not flat, the map $ (IA)\otimes B \to I(A \otimes B) $ induced by $ (IA)\times B \to I(A\otimes B) $, $ (ia , b) \mapsto i(a\otimes b) $ is definitely surjective, but not injective.